# function to return key of object if given value

Tags: coffeescript

If given an object such as:

```
  taste =
    0: "Hate"
    1: "Really Dislike"
    2: "Dislike"
    3: ""
    4: "Like"
    5: "Really Like"
    6: "Love"
```

I am looking of a function that will return the key if given the value. I tried the following

```
  Object::getKeyByVal = (value) ->
    for prop of this
      return prop  if this[prop] is value  if @hasOwnProperty(prop)
```

Using this, alert time.getKeyByVal("< 1.5 hours") will acutally return 8, but it gives an error that kills the rest of the script;

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function (value) {
      var prop;
      for (prop in this) {
        if (this.hasOwnProperty(prop) ? this[prop] === value : void 0) {
          return prop;
        }
      }
    } has no method 'exec'
```

Is there a better way of getting the key of a given value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
getKeyFromValue = (obj,value)->
  for own k,v of obj
    if v==value
      return k

o =
  a:1
  b:2
  c:3
  d:4

console.log(getKeyFromValue(o,3)) # should output c
```

[Check out a live demo](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3agetKeyFromValue%20=%20%28obj,value%29-%3E%0A%20%20for%20own%20k,v%20of%20obj%0A%20%20%20%20if%20v==value%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20k%0A%0A%0A%0Ao%20=%0A%20%20a:1%0A%20%20b:2%0A%20%20c:3%0A%20%20d:4%0A%0Aconsole.log%28getKeyFromValue%28o,3%29%29%20#%20should%20output%20c%0A)